# Ruby - Array of Hashes - Undefined method 'each' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I'm wanting to iterate through the array of hashes and print the values to the terminal.

Currently receiving an error:

```
main.rb:14:in `print': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from main.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I'm wanting to iterate through, as opposed to something simple like`puts @transactions`

Any ideas why I'm receiving this error? Thanks

```
class TestRun
   @transactions = [
      {:repayment_number => 1, :repayment_amount => 224.34},
      {:repayment_number => 2, :repayment_amount => 241.50},
      {:repayment_number => 3, :repayment_amount => 135.04},
      {:repayment_number => 4, :repayment_amount => 91.00}
   ]

   def print()
      @transactions.each do |t|
         puts "#{t[:repayment_number]} - #{t[:repayment_amount]}"
      end
   end

end

@test = TestRun.new
@test.print()
```

Comment: `@transactions` is being defined on the eigenclass `TestRun`, rather than instances of `TestRun`.

Answer (score 5):

You have defined `@transactions` twice, initially when `self` equals `TestRun`, making it a *class instance variable*, then within the `print` method, when `self` is the instance `TestRun.new`, making that one an *instance variable*. Those two variables are as different as `@night` and `@day`.

Here are three ways to make your code work (the first two being for educational purposes only).

**Make *print* a class method**

```
class TestRun
  puts "self at class level = #{self}"
  @transactions = [
    {:repayment_number => 1, :repayment_amount => 224.34},
    {:repayment_number => 2, :repayment_amount => 241.50}
  ]
  def self.print
    puts "self within self.print = #{self}"
    @transactions.each do |t|
      puts "#{t[:repayment_number]} - #{t[:repayment_amount]}"
    end
  end
end
  #=> self at class level = TestRun
TestRun.print
  #=> self within self.print = TestRun
  #   1 - 224.34
  #   2 - 241.5
```

**Access the class instance variable from within the method print**

```
class TestRun
  @transactions = [
    {:repayment_number => 1, :repayment_amount => 224.34},
    {:repayment_number => 2, :repayment_amount => 241.50}
  ]
  def print
    puts "self within print = #{self}"
    self.class.instance_variable_get(:@transactions).each do |t|
      puts "#{t[:repayment_number]} - #{t[:repayment_amount]}"
    end
  end
end

TestRun.new.print
  #=> self within print = #<TestRun:0x007fcccb13f390>
  #   1 - 224.34
  #   2 - 241.5
```

**Define @transactions within the initialize method, making it an instance variable**

This is what @31piy has done, and most likely what is intended by the OP.

```
class TestRun
  def initialize
    puts "self within initialize = #{self}"    
    @transactions = [
      {:repayment_number => 1, :repayment_amount => 224.34},
      {:repayment_number => 2, :repayment_amount => 241.50}
    ]
  end
  def print
    puts "self within print = #{self}"
    @transactions.each do |t|
      puts "#{t[:repayment_number]} - #{t[:repayment_amount]}"
    end
  end
end

TestRun.new.print
  #=> self within initialize = #<TestRun:0x007fcccb2ae988>
  #   self within print = #<TestRun:0x007fcccb2ae988>
  #   1 - 224.34
  #   2 - 241.5
```

Comment: The answer by @31piy has an incorrect wording and in general just blindly shows “how other people usually do it.” Thanks for putting this great explanation here. Upvoted, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The `@transactions` is `nil` because it is not initialized as an instance variable. The `initialize` method can be used to create this when the class object is created.

You need to correct your code to leverage it.

```
class TestRun
   def initialize
     @transactions = [
       {:repayment_number => 1, :repayment_amount => 224.34},
       {:repayment_number => 2, :repayment_amount => 241.50},
       {:repayment_number => 3, :repayment_amount => 135.04},
       {:repayment_number => 4, :repayment_amount => 91.00}
     ]
   end

   def print()
      @transactions.each do |t|
         puts "#{t[:repayment_number]} - #{t[:repayment_amount]}"
      end
   end

end

@test = TestRun.new
@test.print()
```

Comment: “The `initialize` method is used to initialize instance variables of a class.”—it might be used for that, but it’s initial purpose is far from this.

Comment: @mudasobwa Agreed. What I mentioned is one way to do it. **Cary Swoveland**'s answer is much more explanatory.

Comment: @mudasobwa so, what is the initial purpose of `initialize`?

Comment: @Stefan to perform an initialization of an object, that might include but is not limited to instance variables settings. E.g. `DbConnection` singleton class might establish a connection to the database, and `TestHelper` might prepare the database content with fixtures. On the other hand, lazy getters are almost everywhere do better, than an initialization in `initialize`. I have a nifty proof of that thesis, but the margins here are too small to put it in :)

Comment: "The `initialize` method is used to initialize instance variables of a class." – No. It is used to initialize *objects*, not *classes*.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. It means a lot. I've again tried to correct the explanation of my answer.